# Basic issue in copying files from hive or hadoop to local directory due to wrong nomenclature

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I'm trying to copy a file that is hosted both within Hive and on an HDFS onto my local computer, but I can't seem to figure out the write call/terminology to use to invoke my local. All online explanations describe it solely as "path to local". I'm trying to copy this into a folder at `C/Users/PC/Desktop/data` and am using the following attempts:

In HDFS

```
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /user/w205/staging /C/Users/PC/Desktop/data
```

In Hive

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'c/users/pc/desktop/data/' SELECT * FROM lacountyvoters;
```

How should I be invoking the local repository in this case?

Comment: Just to be clear when you are talking about local, do you mean the local file system on a machine in the Hadoop cluster. Meaning a machine which has hive and hdfs installed? If so, can you maybe share the errors you are getting.

Comment: If not you need to first transfer the file to local and then copy it to your remote desktop using for example secure copy.